# ascii codec can't decode

Tags: list, python-3.x, encoding, ascii, utf

I am getting an error on trying to open all .txt files in my directory, and when I have only 1 txt file in the directory my code works, otherwise this message pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Name/Desktop/TCSS 142/Project 2/project2.py", line 17, in <module>
for line in file:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
   return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is my code:

```
import glob

# Returns a list of all filenames ending in .txt
# precondition: none
# postcondition: a list of all filenames in the current directory
#                with a .txt extension
def getFilesInDir():
    filenames = glob.glob('./*.txt')
    for i in range(len(filenames)):
        filenames[i] = filenames[i][2:]
    return filenames

files = getFilesInDir()

for el in files:
    file = open(el, 'r')
    for line in file:
        print(line)
    file.close()
```

Comment: try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` this in top of your file

Comment: Could you post the full traceback?

Comment: 0x92 is the (single, right) smart quote, which presumably is in one of your files, and may hide itself as a simple ascii apostrophe `'`.

Comment: @Evert Could you explain what a full traceback is?

Comment: Don't you also use `codecs`? Because your error is about `codecs.ascii_decode` and you do not use it in your code.

Comment: Full traceback: the complete error message: all lines.

Comment: Try to use `    file = open(el, 'r', encoding='utf-8')`. The default encoding (in your case) is ASCII, which obviously doesn't work. UTF-8 will likely work better.

Comment: An alternative encoding if utf-8 doesn't work, might be "cp1252" (Windows, Western Europe), since the 0x92 code seems to be Windows specific. See the [list of Python encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Comment: When I try that I get 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 3: invalid start byte'

Answer (score 0):

Ok so @Evert 's comment fixed my problem, when I opened the file, so my open statement looked like this:

```
file = open(el, 'r', encoding = 'cp1252')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your default encoding (for reading files) appears to be ASCII; the character it can't read appears to be a (Windows) smart quote ("curly" apostrophe `'`).

To be able to read the file, you need to specify its encoding. I don't think `0x92` is a valid UTF code point (but I may be mistaken); since it's a Windows smart quote, try the [Windows latin alphabet encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) `cp1252`:

```
file = open(el, 'r', encoding = 'cp1252')
```